# PowerShell code to export to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I have two Powershell scrips below and they do different things but I need them to do roughly similar things when they export to CSV.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\user\Desktop\here -Recurse |
  where {!$_.PSIsContainer} |
  Select-Object * |
  Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\Users\user\Desktop\Output\output.csv |
  % {$_.Replace('"','')}
```

Gets me all the detailed info about a directory and when I open the CSV in Excel everything is in separate columns - Perfect.

```
plink.exe -ssh root@user -pw password -m C:\Users\user\Desktop\Scrips\LinuxScriptCommand.txt > C:\Users\user\Desktop\Output\Linux.csv
```

Runs `df -h` on my cloud and returns the space left on my drives, which is what I want, but when I open this CSV in Excel it makes me go through the text import wizard which the other doesn't.

I can't figure out a way to automate the text wizard part, can anyone provide me some insight? Also if you have a way to optimize it please let me know too.

Comment: If your `plink.exe` command (ultimately) runs `df -h`, the result will _not_ be a CSV file - instead, you'll get _whitespace-separated_ columns.

Comment: As an aside: `| Select-Object *` serves no obvious purpose and neither does `| % {$_.Replace('"','')}`, given that `Export-Csv` produces no output (except writing to a _file_) and therefore sends nothing through the pipeline.

Comment: Why don't you rewrite whatever plink.exe is doing in PowerShell?  You're trying to get the same output out of two very different methods.  The question isn't very well defined.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Presumably because he doesn't have PowerShell on the Linux(?) host `plink` is running the command(s) on.

Comment: Yes, I do not have powershell on linux, so I am using putty (plink) to ssh into it and run the commands.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `df -h` command to output with comma separated values:

```
df -h | awk '{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6" "$7}'
```

The issue you were having with it saving to a single cell is the UNIX line endings not displaying correctly in Windows. This can be fixed by replacing them:

```
plink.exe -ssh root@user -pw password -m C:\Users\user\Desktop\Scrips\LinuxScriptCommand.txt | foreach { 
    if (([regex] "`r`n$").IsMatch($_) -eq $false) { $_ -replace "`n", "`r`n" } else { $_ } 
} | Set-Content "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Output\Linux.csv"
```

---

If you're using a newer version of Powershell you can use the `-File` param to only return files. Which makes your other command considerably shorter when you remove the other unnecessary parts:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\user\Desktop\here -Recurse -File | Export-CSV C:\Users\user\Desktop\Output\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hello, This made everything open in 1 cell instead of bringing up the text wizard..

Comment: It's the UNIX line endings, I've updated my answer to fix this.